# Cross join in SSIS without using any DB connection

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, ssis-2012

I have 2 flat file source with only one column in each.
First flat file as 1,2,3 as its data.
Second flat file as A,B,C as it data.

I want the cross join output of this into another flat file. I dont have any DB connection to use or basically I'm not allowed to use the DB connection. can I know which all transformations can help in doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Merge Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141775.aspx) transformation and use **Full Outer Join** for Join Type.